# Flex flow not working in IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

In IE11 (Edge mode), I have this code

```css
.A {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.B {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: tomato;
}
.fix {
  width: 600px;
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="A">
  <div class="B">
    foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo
  </div>
  <div class="C">
    <div class="fix">bar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In chrome, it will actually wrap when screen width is small enough, but in IE11 Edge mode, it does not wrap and just overlays on each other. I found this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127300(v=vs.85).aspx saying that flex-flow should be defined and w3schools says its defined for IE11.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-flow.asp

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

This is what it looks like in IE11 (edge mode):
[image]

And in chrome:
[image]

Comment: Note: I repeat **IE11 (edge mode)** not Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.B` element has `flex: 1` applied.

This computes to:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 0%` (in Chrome, FF, Edge)
- `flex-basis: 0px` (in IE11)

IE11 takes this to mean the flex item can shrink to 0, hence the overlap.

Instead of `flex: 1` use `flex: auto`, which computes to

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: auto` (content length)

https://jsfiddle.net/s26rdfbw/3/

[More details about `flex: auto` in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common).